# Using Enter_Frame as a timer Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs4

I am trying to save memory and space. So instead of using the Timer for my application, I was thinking about using my main loop (ENTER_FRAME) to keep track of time that passes. Is there anything wrong about this ??

Comment: I would recommend it as the way to go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the situation, but either way you might want to have a look at some utility
functions like [getTimer()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/utils/package.html#getTimer()) and [setTimeout()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/utils/package.html#setTimeout());

Goodluck!

Comment: setTimeout() just wraps a regular Timer, so that's really not saving any memory at all. getTimer() is the way to go if you need to keep track of actual time passed.